# UIDatePicker hours interval (NSCalendarUnit?)

Tags: iphone, datepicker, uidatepicker

I'm trying to make a UIDatePicker which allows the selection of hours only between 6.00 and 17.00. The other hours shall be inactive but still visible.
I think it can be done with setting up the picker calendar and then use this:

```
- (NSRange)maximumRangeOfUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)unit
```

but I'm not sure how.

Maybe someone can help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but UIDatePicker doesn't support setting valid time ranges like you describe. The only options are minimum and maximum dates.

You'll either need to build a custom control from scratch or try to subclass UIDatePicker, but that's not a path I'd recommend.

Comment: Thank you Kirk , 
I still think you can set a range for a NSCalendar (see http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/rangeOfUnit:inUnit:forDate: ), and tell UIDatePiker to use that calendar , right?

Comment: No, that's a read only property on NSCalendar, and creating your own NSCalendar (if that's even possible) is a far worse option (localization, bugs, etc..) than just using UIPickerView to build a custom control.