# Time range on date picker for specific dates iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uidatepicker

I want to have a time range on a UIDatePicker, so I can display what times users can book a meeting. Say on May 25th, they can book between 12pm and 8 pm, if they scroll to May 26th they can book between 4pm and 8pm.

So I'm wondering how I can display this in a UIDatePicker? Users can't choose time outside of a preset I have for each day.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to add a target to the date picker, and check if the time of the date chosen matched the hours I preset and display an alert view if they didn't match.

Answer (score 1):

I found this one, hope this will help you out..

[Can UIDatePicker's minimumDate and maximumDate include time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441282/can-uidatepickers-minimumdate-and-maximumdate-include-time)

Enjoy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but no. UIDatePicker can only set ranges for dates. If you want to restrict the range of the hours, you will have to subclass uidatepicker and create your own custom class.
Here's a link: [UIDatePicker hours interval (NSCalendarUnit?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377167/uidatepicker-hours-interval-nscalendarunit)
Hope this helped!

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that. This functionality is critical for my app as far as user experience goes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using UIPickerView to make your own date picker. Every time a date is selected, you can change what times are available inside pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:.

Comment: can't I do the same if add a target to the datepicker?

Comment: Unfortunately, since the SDK only allows you to set a minimum and a maximum date on UIDatePicker, the only way to restrict the time would be to also restrict the date. If you made your own, you could allow the date component to spin freely and restrict only the time components based on the date selected.

Comment: Let us know which way you choose, but I think this is your best option. Don't forget to pick an answer :-)