# iOS uidatepicker set time for each day

Tags: ios, iphone, time, uidatepicker

I want my iPhone app to have a date&time picker with constraints on time 10 AM to 5 PM for all future days. For example,my user should be able to select today with maximum of 5 PM or a future date with time between 10 am and 5 pm.

The minimum and maximum date properties doesnt help me with my requirement. Any possible solution? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIDatePicker doesn't appear to support a minimum or maximum time, only date.

You will have to either subclass UIDatePicker and create your own, or possibly alert the user when they select something out of your bounds.

A similar question was posted here: [Time range on date picker for specific dates iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740778/time-range-on-date-picker-for-specific-dates-iphone)

Comment: You could look at the example here of implementing a hebrew date picker, it gives some idea on how to customize the picker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004778/how-do-i-rewrite-the-uidatepicker-component